# Deserialization of a json string gives null value

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

```
{
  "apple": {
    "A": "xyz",
    "B": "abc",
    "C": "jkl"
  },
  "banana": {
    "A": "lotus",
    "B": "oil",
    "C": "cat"
  }
}
```

This is my JSON and below is my model class where I want to map the JSON data.

```
 public class Wrapper
    {
        public Dictionary<string, item> fruits{ get; set; }
    }
public class item
    {
        public string A{get; set;}
        public string B{get; set;}
        public string C{get; set;}
    }
```

when I am using the following code to deserialize the Json string I am getting null as response.

```
 var value=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wrapper>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Your wrapper type expects an object with a single property, `fruits`. Your JSON doesn't define an object with a `fruits` property. Your JSON would have to be `{ "fruits": { "apple": {/*...*/}, "banana": {/*...*/} }`.

Answer (score 3):

you don't need any wrapper

```
var value=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, item>>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wrap in an element `fruits`:

```
{
  "fruits":
  {
    "apple": {
      "A": "xyz",
      "B": "abc",
      "C": "jkl"
    },
    "banana": {
      "A": "lotus",
      "B": "oil",
      "C": "cat"
    }
  } 
}
```

To validate that your input is correct - instantiate an instance of the wrapper class and serialise it - then you can compare that your input matches the structure.

Comment: Why not just deserialize what they have, as Serge shows?

Comment: Because that doesn't match what's being asked in the question.

Comment: We read the question different, but that's okay.